# libcurl - easy.h configuration prob

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, php-5.2

my php installation has got some problem while installing I am getting 
following error:

configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
    easy.h should be in /include/curl/

which version of the libcurl should i use for php-5.2.8 installation

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Try With This
None of these will allow you to compile PHP with cURL enabled.

In order to compile with cURL, you need libcurl header files (.h files). They are usually found in /usr/include/curl. They generally are bundled in a separate development package.

Per example, to install libcurl in Ubuntu:

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-dev

Then you can just do:

./configure --with-curl # other options...
If you compile cURL manually, you can specify the path to the files without the lib or include suffix. (e.g.: /usr/local if cURL headers are in /usr/local/include/curl).
```

Comment: no use I have installed libcurl3_7.21.0-1ubuntu1.3_i386.deb but the same error                                                                                but I am not able to find .h files in /usr/include ... i dnt even see curl folder in /usr/include ?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help, I had to do some PHP work on one project and the following are the steps I have done and documented for future, hopefully it will be some use to you or some other people.

**Setup PHP, MySql on Ubuntu 12.4**

1- Install Apache2:
sudo apt-get install apache2
- Open up any web browser and then enter `http://localhost/`

You should see a folder entitled apache2-default/. Open it and you will see a message saying "It works!" , congrats to you!

2-Install PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

- Restart apache2

  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

3- Test PHP

```
sudo gedit /var/www/testphp.php
```

- This will open up a file called phptest.php.
- Copy/Paste this line into the phptest file:
- Save and close the file,  open you're web browser and type the following into the web address: `http://localhost/testphp.php`

-you should see a long file opened

4- Install MySQL

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

-In order for other computers on your network to view the server you have created, you must first edit the "Bind Address". Begin by opening up Terminal to edit the my.cnffile.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

-Change the line
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
And change the 127.0.0.1 to your IP address.
-This is where things may start to get tricky. Begin by typing the following into Terminal:

```
mysql -u root
```

-Following that copy/paste this line:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

-(Make sure to change yourpassword to a password of your choice.)
- install a program called phpMyAdmin which is an easy tool to edit your databases.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

-After that is installed our next task is to get PHP to work with MySQL. To do this we will need to open a file entitled php.ini. To open it type the following:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Now we are going to have to uncomment the following line by taking out the semicolon (;).
Change this line:

```
;extension=mysql.so
```

To look like this:

```
extension=mysql.so
```

Now just restart Apache and you are all set!

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to install php-5.2.8 on ubuntu-10.10 which does not have Long Term Support from ubuntu community .And I need to install most of package manually because of that I am getting following error for php-5.2.8 installation. configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
    easy.h should be in <curl-dir>/include/curl/

Comment: Try installing curl-devel see if that help: yum -y install curl-devel